# Event Evaluation

Tags: javascript

When does a JavaScript event like keydown actually get evaluated.
ie. Till when can one use event.preventDefault() or similar methods to prevent the action from being taken.

I haven't had any luck in trying to find a pattern. All I know that is that if the prevent is executed at the beginning or a statement later, it works(prevents action) but a little later, it doesn't.

Is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably browser dependent. If you want to prevent the default then that instruction should always be the first (no motif not to be, it's instantaneous) and only then follow up with your code.

check the example in http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: But, then does that mean that it would be impossible to prevent specific characters from being entered?

Comment: Guess so.. just prevent the default action, verify the input character and manually execute the expected event with it.